# Почему echo count(""); возвращает 1?

Tags: php

Почему `echo count("");` возвращает 1 если строка пустая?

Answer (score 1):

читаем [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php)

> count
>
> Возвращаемые значения
>
> Возвращает количество элементов в value. До
> PHP 8.0.0, если параметр не был ни массивом (array), ни объектом
> (object), реализующим интерфейс Countable, возвращалось 1, если
> значение параметра value не было null, в этом случае возвращалось 0.